# if function in PYTHON pandas for specific cells

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Im trying to create a function where it reads threw all my rows and columns and simultaneously reading the value of the specific cells. Depending on the value of the material column I want it to write the company down.

I got have an Excel document with different materials and companies.

So, if we say that the material column notes on a specific row that the material is iron I want it to print the company name.

The excel basically looks like this:

---

Material Company

Iron____Microsoft

Plastic_Sony

---

Where "Material" and "Company" are different columns.

If the material is read as Iron I want to print what the Company column returns.

The code I currently have is:

````
#Where the provided path for excel file is stated below
material_data_df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop\materials.xlsx')

df = pd.DataFrame(material_data_df, columns=['material in drawing'])

# print whole sheet data
print(material_data_df) ```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can easily filter the dataframe by the "Material" column, getting back a subset of the original dataframe with your desired value for that column.

```
material_data_df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop\materials.xlsx')
        
df = pd.DataFrame(material_data_df, columns=['material in drawing'])
        
# print whole sheet data
print(df)
    
# Filter the data to only match the ones with "Iron" as a material
    
filtered_df = df[df["Material"] == "Iron"]
    
# Print the names of the companies with "Iron" as a material
    
print(filtered_df["Company"])
```

Edit: to also filter out companies with the name "-", you can simply filter out those as well like this:

```
filtered_df = df[(df["Material"] == "Iron") & (df["Company"] != "-")]
```

You can concatenate pandas conditions using the & (and) operator, surrounding each condition with parenthesis. You can put as many conditions as you want like this. There is also the OR operator, represented by the simbol |

Comment: One more question. In my excel I have listed some materials as "Iron" with a company name that I do not want to print. Is it possible to remove those from the output? For example, if I have a company with the name "-" and want those to not be printed in the filtered output, how do I proceed?

Comment: In that case, you can easily also filter out those. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

path = r'C:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop\materials.xlsx'

# Where the provided path for excel file is stated below
material_data_df = pd.read_excel(path)

# print the dataframe for Iron in the Material column
print(material_data_df[df["Material"] == "Iron"])

# print the Company values for the rows where Iron in the Material column
material_data_df[df["Material"] == "Iron"].apply(lambda row: print(row["Company"]), axis=1)
```